# Access to mobile device camera with flutter app that integrates vue3 website

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, vue.js, flutter-inappwebview

i'm struggling integrating a camera functionality.
I have a vue3 website that should be embedded within a flutter app.
The flutter app should just integrate the mobile-view of the vue3 website.
Nothing else.
I used this: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro/
To embed the website into the flutter app - and this works so far. I can interact with the website via the flutter app.

Now I additionally implemented a new route, that uses the following codepen, to integrate a camera functionality: https://codepen.io/ditarahma08/pen/GRRxZLW
In the browser, during local development of the vue3 component, the camera stream works and is displayed correctly on my vue app in the browser.
But when I host the website within my flutter app, the video stream is not established...

If I start my flutter app and navigate to the route with the camera functionality, the camera stream isn't established and within my console that runs the flutter app, I get the following error:
`flutter: {message: [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler at <Scanner> at <QPage> at <ScannerView onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< [object Object] > > at <RouterView> at <QPageContainer class="bg-primary" > at <QLayout view="lHh Lpr lFf" > at <App>, messageLevel: 2}`

Now I'm kinda clueless what this issue is related to...
Does this appear, because this codepen example only works for my MacBooks front camera, but not for my Iphones Front/Back camera? I was expecting, that it will connect to the Iphones front camera.

I was wondering if this is an issue with the xCode simulator, my Iphone or even with this inappview plugin, which adds an additional abstraction layer, which disables the video stream functionality. Is it even possible to archive this feature like I am trying to? This is the first time I'm working with flutter and vue. Maybe I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here.

Maybe somebody's having some thoughts for me to consider while trying to fix this issue.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue, by using a complete qr-code-reader component.

I tried this one first: https://gruhn.github.io/vue-qrcode-reader/
But I ran into several issues with it and found out, that is doesn't seem to be compatible with vue3.

Found this lib, that provides nearly the same functionality (except the torch ):) and is compatible with vue3: https://github.com/HJ29/vue3-qr-reader